# Why do SEC offering circulars say "X Corp is not legally related to X Inc"

Tags: investing, sec

Reviewing this offering circular: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1786471/000119312522234216/d283521d253g2.htm - it includes the following language:

> In this Offering Circular, the term “Aptera” or “the company” refers to Aptera Motors Corp., a Delaware corporation, and its subsidiary, Andromeda Interfaces, Inc., a California corporation, on a consolidated basis. Aptera is not legally related to Aptera Motors Inc.

I'm having trouble understanding this.

Literally parsing this:

Premise:

- "Aptera" equals "Aptera Motors Corp"
- "Aptera" not equal "Aptera Motors Inc"

Conclusion:

- "Aptera Motors Corp" not equal "Aptera Motors Inc"

I cannot find any other company named Aptera, and I always thought that the process of incorporating resulted in a Corporation. But this seems to be making a distinction.  And I really doubt there are two different car manufacturers both named "Aptera".

I assume this statement is in some way meant to fully let investors know potential risks, but I don't understand what this actually implies.

What is going on here?

Comment: **There WAS** a different company with the same name (and basically the same idea). See the second and third paragraphs of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptera_Motors .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a previous iteration of the company with the same founders and the same product (electric vehicle), thus the desire to avoid confusion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptera_Motors#History